# "Unable to find image named XXX on watch" when I use image cache

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I use `- (BOOL)addCachedImage:(UIImage *)image name:(NSString *)name` API of `WKInterfaceDevice` to store images.

The issue is that most of the time, when I try to use those cached image by using `setImageNamed:` on `WKInterfaceImage`, I get this `Unable to find image named XXX on watch` error that results in an empty image on screen.
I insist on the fact that this does NOT happen all the time.

This occurs both on simulator and on device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that image names that are too long (character count > 255) lead to the bug. As soon as the image name used to cache the image is shorter, I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: I haven't heard of an issue like this. Can you provide an example of the names that weren't working? Also, did you ever look at `[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages]` to check the names?

Comment: Set any very long name in `addCachedImage: name` and you should get an error, there's no need for me to give you an example. And yes, I do check `[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages]` correctly, my code works very well as soon as names are not too long anyway.

Comment: It might not be related to names but to hashes though. I'll investigate more tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, let me precise that the value returned for a long name when I call `[[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages] objectForKey:verylongName]` is != 0 and is the size of the image, as expected.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been using full UUID strings (about 57 characters) with no problems. Could be related to the issues that are being reported with Xcode 6.3, though.

Comment: Yeah, I had put in place my own naming convention (a combination of hash of different parameters of my image loading request) which could end up generating longer strings than 57 characters. And yes, it could be a Xcode 6.3 bug though, as mentioned in this forum ticket (https://devforums.apple.com/message/1132608#1132608).

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Assets.xcassets` in the Project Navigator on the left sidebar in XCode.

There choose the image that is not found.

For me it worked as soon as I had the image placed in the "2x" placeholder.

If you just import the images they are placed in the 1x spot, but the Apple Watches seem to need at least the 2x resolution. Just optimize your images and it will all work seamlessly.

Comment: I was working with downloaded images that I wanted to store in the watch cache. So no static images in my case. This was just an apple bug (if we can call it a bug), see the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an Xcode bug, I am facing this issue in Xcode 7 beta 4 but not in beta 2. I researched and experimented many things including various suggestions, and it turns out that if the images are set at Universal they are not getting picked up (http://iphone.tagsstack.com/unable_to_find_image_named_ldquo_xxrdquo_on_iwatch_error). However, if you select them separately for each of the watch size, they will show up and the issue is resolved.